# Is getting a blank window normal when making a graph API call?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Using Graph API 5 and Azure Identity
*App Registration Details*: 
-- **Platform Configuration:** Native Client 
-- **Allow Public Client Flows** = "yes" 
-- **Delegated permissions:** Files.ReadWrite.All, User.Read
**OS:** Windows 11 Enterprise
**Application Type:** Console
**.NET Version:** Framework 4.8.1

Admin consent has already been granted to everyone in the organization.  The end user will not get a screen that prompts for permissions.

The code does exactly what it's supposed to do, but I notice that when the Graph API call is made, a blank window pops-up for about a second then disappears.

Is that normal?  Shouldn't the code just run without any pop ups?
  The code shown below is what I use to authenticate.

The end user calls **GetGraphServiceClient** to get a GraphServiceClient object.

```
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Core.Diagnostics;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Net.WebRequestMethods;

namespace Authenticator
{
    public class GraphAuthentication
    {
        private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;

        private static readonly string TOKEN_CACHE_NAME = "TokenCache.bin";
        private static readonly string tokenCachePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") + "\\" + TOKEN_CACHE_NAME;

        private static readonly string clientId = "-- CLIENT ID --";
        private static readonly string tenantId = "-- TENANT ID --"; 
        private static readonly string scopeStrings = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
        private static readonly string redirectUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient"; 


        private static InteractiveBrowserCredential interactiveCredential;
        private static readonly InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = tenantId,
            ClientId = clientId,
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
            RedirectUri = new Uri(redirectUri),
            BrowserCustomization = new BrowserCustomizationOptions { UseEmbeddedWebView = true },


            TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new TokenCachePersistenceOptions { Name = TOKEN_CACHE_NAME },



            Diagnostics =
                    {
                        ApplicationId = DiagnosticsOptions.DefaultApplicationId,
                        LoggedHeaderNames = { "x-ms-request-id" },
                        LoggedQueryParameters = { "api-version" },
                        IsLoggingEnabled = true,
                        IsLoggingContentEnabled = true
                    }
        };

        public static GraphServiceClient GetGraphServiceClient(string loginHint)
        {
            if (graphClient != null) return graphClient;

            options.LoginHint = loginHint;

            List<string> scopes = new List<string> { scopeStrings };
            AzureEventSourceListener listener = new AzureEventSourceListener((e, message) =>
            {
                // Only log messages from Azure-Core event source
                if (e.EventSource.Name == "Azure-Core")
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("graphCalls.log", true))
                    {
                        writer.Write(message);
                    }
                }
            },

            level: System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel.Verbose);

            AuthenticationRecord authRecord;
            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(tokenCachePath) == false)
                {
                    // https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.identity.interactivebrowsercredential
                    interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);


                    TokenRequestContext tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scopeStrings });
                    
                    // Call AuthenticateAsync to fetch a new AuthenticationRecord.
                    authRecord = interactiveCredential.Authenticate(tokenRequestContext);

                    // Serialize the AuthenticationRecord to disk so that it can be re-used across executions of this initialization code.
                    using (var authRecordStream = new System.IO.FileStream(tokenCachePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        authRecord.SerializeAsync(authRecordStream).Wait();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (var authRecordStream = new System.IO.FileStream(tokenCachePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        authRecord = AuthenticationRecord.DeserializeAsync(authRecordStream).Result;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Deserialized AuthenticationRecord.");

                        options.AuthenticationRecord = authRecord;
                        interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);
                    }
                }



                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e);
            }

            return graphClient;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would edge a bet on the following causing that popup due to no user authentication token being in the cache already.
`authRecord = interactiveCredential.Authenticate(tokenRequestContext);` In this case, yes it would be expected but only for the first call, subsequent calls should not trigger a popup

Comment: When using the InteractiveBrowserCredential, the blank window that appears when a Graph API request is normal. This is so that the credential can authenticate the user by means of an embedded web view. After the user has authenticated and granted permission, the window should close.

Comment: @Rukmini So this is normal behavior then?

Comment: AFAIK it is normal behavior. Shall I post it as an answer?

Comment: @bolt-io The first time the application is used, one would expect a pop-up window to request the grant of the permissions listed in it.   However, in this case, the window always pops-up blank.   The user is not asked for their credentials and the application proceeds successfully.  I just thought it was odd that acquiring a token silently would have this happen.

Comment: @Rukmini sure, post as an answer.   I wait a little more corroboration before I more it as "the" answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255268/discussion-between-rukmini-and-ezg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** that: When using the `InteractiveBrowserCredential`, the blank window that appears when a Graph API request is normal. This is so that the credential can authenticate the user by means of an embedded web view. After the user has authenticated and granted permission, the window should close.

- This is because Azure Identity to authenticate the user and obtain an access token uses a web browser. The blank window is the web browser that is being used to perform the authentication.
- Otherwise, you can make use of `ClientSecretCredential` where it does not require user interaction and can be used to authenticate without displaying a login page.

In your code, you can modify it by calling any Microsoft Graph call like below:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
```

**References:**

[Get a user - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

[OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow on the Microsoft identity platform - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret)